# Is $v=\ (r_i)^{-1}\cdot z $, a uniformly random value of a field?

Tags: group-theory, probability-distributions, finite-fields

We consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=2p+1$ and $q$ and $p$ are prime numbers.

Let $r_i$ be a value picked uniformly at random from the field such that $r_i>\frac{q}{2}$. Let $z$ be a fixed field element.

**Question:** Is $v=(\ (r_i)^{-1}\cdot z) \bmod q$, a uniformly random value of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the restriction $r_i > \frac{q}{2}$ means $v$ can only assume $2p + 1 - (p + 1) = p$ different values.

Comment: Can I say that $v$ is distributed uniformly random in a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_q$? , where the subfield order is $p$?

Comment: It is uniformly distributed on a subset of $\mathbb{F}_q$, but this subset is never a field. Note that $\mathbb{F}_q$ doesn't even have any proper subfield.

Comment: Thanks. Since my question is related to security I'd like to ask: Knowing $v$, can one guess value  $z$ with probability better  than $\frac{1}{p}$?

Comment: Knowing a single vale of $v$? probably not. You should just simulate this scenario and examine how the possible values of $v$ intersect for different values of $z$.