# How To Prove that $v=r\cdot z\ $ is Distributed Uniformly at Random

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, finite-fields

I consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=2p+1$, and $p$ , $q$ are prime numbers.

Let $z$ be a fixed element of the field. Also let $r$ be a value picked uniformly random from the field where $r>\frac{q}{2}$

---

**Question:** How to prove that $v=r\cdot z\ $ is distributed uniformly random in subset of the field where the  subset's size is $p$?

Comment: This is the same problem: [Is $v=\ (r_i)^{-1}\cdot z $, a uniformly random value of a field?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423174/is-v-r-i-1-cdot-z-a-uniformly-random-value-of-a-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $x \mapsto xz$ is a bijection unless $z = 0$. This immediately yields the assertion.